# How to use Dataset inside a model in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dataset, ado.net

This is the view, I am getting the data from table 0 from dataset by using @model Dataset.

```
@using System.Data;
    @using WebApplication4.Models;
    @model Dataset;

         <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr">
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>View</th>
            </thead>

            </tr>
            @foreach(DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@row["account"]</td>
                    <td>@row["amount"]</td>
                    <td>@row["date"]</td>
                    <td>@row["type"]</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='/HOME/TransactionInfo?id=@row["transactionid"]'">View details</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
          </table>
```

I want to use another model ie., **MyViewModel** that consists of

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string MyRadioField { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string incomeType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As I cannot import two models like this:

```
@model Dataset;
@model MyViewModel;
```

How can I put this Dataset inside MyViewModel, so that I can use only @model MyviewModel to get all data?

Please help me.

Comment: Create a wrapper class which has properties of type viewmodel and dataset. And use that class a model in the view.

Comment: can you provide code for that, I haven't used a wrapper class before

Comment: `public class DatasetModel { public Dataset Dataset {get;set;} public MyViewModel ViewModel {get;set;}}`